# Use result of one query as argument of a command (on a single line)

Tags: powershell

Administering AzureAD, Exchange Online, Teams etc. from PowerShell, I like to save one-liners in a text file that I later call on, but sometimes, the commands require an object ID when all I know is the object's name.

For instance, the cmdlet, `Add-TeamUser`, lets me add a user to a Team group. However, it requires the group ID when I want to supply the name. I can get the group ID from the name via:

```
Get-Team | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "Produce Sales"} | select GroupId
```

Output (partially obscured):

[image]

Is it possible to use that query inline with `Add-TeamUser`? Something like:

`Add-TeamUser -GroupId {the-above-query} -User someone@somewhere.com`

Comment: Should be able to do exactly that but use parenthesis instead. If it gives any issues try adding a $ in front  $(the above query)

Comment: Have you tried this? I get "Invalid object identifier '@{GroupId=xxx.....}'". Perhaps the output of the inner query needs to be more "raw" somehow--just the ID value?

Comment: add-teamuser -groupid (Get-Team | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "Produce Sales"} ).GroupId -user someone@somewhere.com   If you are only going to get one item from a query I always treat the return as an object and get the one property Item (query).property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely, the cmdlet of `Add-TeamUser` accepts input by pipeline. Id run a `Get-Help Add-TeamUser -Full` to see what type of values it accepts so you can just pipe to it. Alternatively, you can just assign the value to a Variable and send it to the next command. In this scenario, we have an array of values and we loop through each one, grabbing JUST the ID, and then adding them by the ID:

```
$ListOfNames = @("Produce Sales","Shoe Sales", "ETC")
    Foreach($name in $ListOfNames){
        $GroupID = Get-Team | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "$name"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty GroupId
            Add-TeamUser -GroupId $GroupID -User someone@somewhere.com
                        }
```

And another way it can be used is to pass it to the `foreach-object` cmdlet and let it take the value from the pipeline for you. It can also be used just at the top sample code did:

```
Get-Team | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "Produce Sales"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty GroupId | ForEach-Object -Process{
     Add-TeamUser -GroupId $_ -User someone@somewhere.com}
```

Comment: Honestly, I can think of 3 other ways this can be done but, it really depends on how you're trying to handle the data. Just ensure you assign the proper email if youre gonna use an array lol

Comment: What you're really looking for is just this though: ` $GroupID = Get-Team | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq "Produce Sales"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty GroupId
            Add-TeamUser -GroupId $GroupID -User someone@somewhere.com`

Comment: Disregard, just saw you asked for a one liner. 2nd example should work for that. You can also include the 1st line in your example, in parentheses and include it as the value for the 2nd line for input. If that makes sense

Comment: The one starting with `Get-Team` worked! It's ugly-ass but it got the job done with a single line. One of the missing "pillars" of knowledge for me was the use of `-ExpandProperty` to get use the raw property value. Thank you! I'll mark this as the answer, if nothing more elegant comes around in the near future.

Comment: Id check the help for `Add-Team` to see if its accepts certain parameters you can pass onto it. Would be a lot cleaner but, glad that worked out for ya!(: